# PHP MySQL INNER JOIN timing out

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 `mysql` tables that look like this...

```
table1

reference | name
---------------------
2738      | John Doe
837       | Jane Doe

table2

refnumber | address1
--------------------------
2738      | 26 My Road
8998      | 6 The Crescent
```

I am trying to join using `inner join` like this....

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN reference 
        ON table1.reference  = table2.refnumber
        LIMIT $offset, 20";

$data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

This is giving me an error 500 and timing out, the tables are quite large with a million entries in each.

Hoe can I do this differently to prevent the timeout?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the columns you're using in the ON clause.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LEFT JOIN table2`?

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` usually is wrong.

Comment: I'm 100% with @Barmar here. If you don't add `ORDER`ing, a `LIMIT` rarely makes any sense.

Comment: What indexes do your tables have?

Comment: Also, if you are using `OFFSET` (you are) you'll need to provide **unique ordering**. Remember that backend pagination requires unique ordering... otherwise it won't make sense at all.

Comment: 2 things: you said you are using an `INNER JOIN` but in your query you are actually using a `LEFT JOIN`. Also, in your query you are selecting from `table1` and left joining `reference` but in the `ON` clause part of your left join you are using `table1` and `table2`. The `LEFT JOIN` wouldn't really cause the query to time out but the inconsistency in your `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use:**

```
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM 
    table1 as t1

    INNER JOIN 
    reference as t2
    ON t1.reference = t2.refnumber

    LIMIT 15, 10
```